# Getting output as:- number:57929.0, number:59214.0, number:57931.0 instead of 57929, 59214,57931

Tags: python, excel, string, int

The following is the code I am trying to execute. But when I execute it, I am not getting the output the way I want.

The output cell has the value `number:57929.0` instead of `57929`.
I know that by using, `a = int(values[i].value)` I am getting proper "57929" as the output.

But I want to do the set operations on it, so when I am converting the `values[]` to the `set()`, the `number:57929.0` values gets into the set variable.

The list "values" contains the value in this "number:57929.0" format, so how do I remove this to get a desired output.

```js
import xlrd
import xlwt

data = xlrd.open_workbook('TAX TCC.xlsx')
table = data.sheet_by_name(u 'WARD 1')

nrows = table.nrows
ncols = table.ncols

data1 = xlrd.open_workbook('WardWiseProperty.xlsx')
table1 = data1.sheet_by_name(u 'Sheet1')
nrows1 = table1.nrows
ncols1 = table1.ncols

values = []
for i in range(nrows - 3):
  values.append(table.cell(i + 3, 0))

values1 = []
for i in range(5902):
  values1.append(table1.cell(i + 10, 5))

sett = set(values)
sett1 = set(values1)

print(sett - sett1)
```

Comment: Can you show us the full stack trace?

Comment: And maybe also reduce the problem to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide input and expected output.

Comment: are the lines that start "values.append..." automatically including text from headers or somesuch?